# how to create facebook profile clone in external website page?

Tags: php, facebook, api

I like to create facebook profile clone on some external page . This page may something look like [this](http://www.sinthaistudio.com/thehouse/alrena/) . And , is it possible to make everything like that page . Let suppose  if we somebody clicked on "add as friend"  he can add me from that page only .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull almost all the information displayed on a Facebook profile via the Graph API, but displaying it in a manner designed to look like Facebook is in direct violation of Facebook policy

Also, check this page: https://www.facebook.com/badges/ - it's not exactly what you're looking for, but lets you put some of your profile information into an external site